# Weird SQL Behaviour

Tags: sql-server-2008

A view that hase been running for years selects specific columns from several tables and joins them.
Recently, I added a column to one of the tables, and the vew no longer worked properly.
One of the columns in the query result contained data that was from another column in the table.
I rebuilt the view from a script - no changes to the script - and the problem went away.
The view does not look at the new column.

What is going on?

Comment: I don't know but if you post the tables and what joins you want and what fields you want in the view we can try to write it for you?

Comment: Please post more specific information about your table structure and sql statements and we may be able to help figure out what is going on.

Comment: What does "no longer worked properly" and "the problem went away" mean? Does your view use `SELECT *`? https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx

Comment: This is known behavior for Views that use "*" in the column lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is using SELECT *.  You simply need to recomple it.

When the view is compiled, it compiles the offset of the fields in the record, rather than the names of the field.  If the underlying table changes . . . well, the offsets no longer go to the correct positions.

I, unfortunately, learned this once upon a time after about 5 hours of trying to figure out why a number was getting a numeric error -- starting at 6:00 a.m.  So, this problem can even effect different types of data.

I do the recompile by scripting out the view as an alter, using SQL Server Management Studio, and then running the code (without any changes).  However, you could change the code by putting in the explicit list of columns, and not having this problem in the future.

You can also set up a script that recompiles all your views every evening, to prevent this problem in the future.  We now have such a script as well.

Comment: Yes, one of the tables uses * and that seems to be the problem.